# Disable new horizontal document group on building in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, configuration, tabs, visual-studio-2019

It's really frustrating and I can't find it useful after eight months. So:

- on building in Visual Studio 2019,
- when there are some errors and I click "Yes" to see them,
- a new horizontal document group appears with the "Error List" window,
- and when I click its entries, new tabs are opened in this new row,
- so I can't quickly look at one place for tabs for open files, I have to jump like a dumb between the lower and the higher group.

How to disable this behavior?

I guess it is useful if we like to work with many open files, but I consider this as counterproductive, I want to be focused, so I constantly close every unnecessary file.

And I like to move sometimes, but there are so many really interesting sports, and we can go outside, a park is near... Why I need to jump from one group of tabs to the other?! For calories, really?

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the Error List tab and select **Dock**.

Comment: Nooo... It shouln't be so easy... :-) I will check it on Monday, for now - thank you for your tip.